# Difference between awk -FS and awk -f in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am new to shell scripting and I'm very confused between `awk -FS` and `awk -f` commands used. I've tried reading multiple pages on the difference between these two but was not able to understand clearly. Kindly help.
Here is an example:
Lets consider that a text file say, `data.txt` has the below details.

```
S.No Product Qty Price
1-Pen-2-10
2-Pencil-1-5
3-Eraser-1-2
```

Now, when i try to use the following command:

```
$ awk -f'-' '{print $1,$2} data.txt
```

I get the below output:

```
1 Pen
2 Pencil
3 Eraser
```

But when i use the command:

`$ awk -FS'-' '{print $1,$2} data.txt`

the output is:

```
1-Pen-2-10
2-Pencil-1-5
3-Eraser-1-2
```

I don't understand the difference it does using the `-FS` command. Could somebody help me out on what exactly happens between these two commands. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You are more confused than you think. There is no `-FS`.

`FS` is a variable that contains the field separator.

`-F` is an option that sets `FS` to it's argument.

`-f` is an option whose argument is the name of a file that contains the script to execute.

The scripts you posted would have produced syntax errors, not the output you say they produced, so idk what to tell you...

Comment: Thank you! i think i understood this concept very badly. my bad. thanks for the clarification. Will work on it.

Comment: Technically `-FS'-'` is the same as `-F "S-"`. So, `echo "QRS-TUV" | awk -FS'-' '{print $1, $2}'` outputs
`QR TUV`

Comment: this was what my doubt was too. but when i try to use `echo "ABC-DEF" | awk -FS'-' '{print $1,$2}'` , I get ABC-DEF only

Comment: @Dev that would be the expected output since `S-` (as stored in `FS`) does not occur anywhere in your input so it only has 1 field so `$1` is `ABC-DEF`. If you check the output you file a blank char added to the end of the line - that's the output field separator (`OFS`) before the null string represented by `$2`. btw wrt your incorrect use of the word `doubt` - the correct English would be `thought` or `expectation` or similar. `doubt` is when you think negatively about something.

Answer (score 3):

`-FS` is not an argument to awk. `-F` is, as is `-f`.

The `-F` argument tells awk what value to use for `FS` (the field separator).

The `-f` argument tells awk to use its argument as the script file to run.

This command (I fixed your quoting):

```
awk -f'-' '{print $1,$2}' data.txt
```

tells awk to use standard input (that's what `-` means) for its argument. This should hang when run in a terminal. And should be an error after that as awk then tries to use `'{print $1,$2}'` as a filename to read from.

This command:

```
awk -FS'-' '{print $1,$2}' data.txt
```

tells awk to use `S-` as the value of `FS`. Which you can see by running this command:

```
awk -FS'-' 'BEGIN {print "["FS"]"}'
```

Comment: Thank you! my bad. need to work on this concept more. thanks for the clarification. Will work on it.